# Insertar uri de spotify a tarjeta nfc

Tags: android, nfc

Intento poner una canción de Spotify a partir de su uri en una tarjeta nfc, para que al pasarla por el lector de mi teléfono se abra la app con la canción.

https://open.spotify.com/track/5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk?si=LAfpZLTmTzG5uNOGYLkKjA

A la tarjeta le grabo este uri

```
spotify:track:5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk
```

Al leer la tarjeta con mi teléfono abre la aplicación pero se queda en el menú principal.

He intentado con

```
spotify:track:5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk#0:0.01
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo

Mi teléfono es un Poco X3 Pro y la aplicación que utilizo es NFC Tools

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que añadirle dos custom URL al NFC:

- Una con la URL completa que obtienes al darle *Compartir* a la canción, quitándole el parámetro que lleva en el GET (lo que va con interrogación,`?5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk`)

Ej: `https://open.spotify.com/track/9875349875v9435394`

- Otra, con el parámetro que estás enviando, `spotify:track:5Z9KJZvQzH6PFmb8SNkxuk`, donde ese track debe ser el mismo ID que quitaste del GET en la URL anterior.